# Laravel array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

i have a very simple route code

```
Route::get("/{id}",function($id){
return view("post.posts",$id);});
```

and a simple code in the view:

```
<div><h1> hello .{{$id}} </h1></div>
```

but i get an exception:
 ErrorException in Factory.php line 167:array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `array` to your view, so instead of

```
Route::get("/{id}",function($id) {
    return view("post.posts",$id);
});
```

where you just pass string, you should use:

```
Route::get("/{id}",function($id) {
    return view("post.posts", ['id' => $id]);
});
```

or alternatively:

```
Route::get("/{id}",function($id) {
    return view("post.posts", compact('id'));
});
```

Comment: @AliEl-Boghdady Glad I could help